# Designing E-commerce database and mysql error

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, phpmyadmin

I am trying to make an e-commerce site from scratch. Currently I am trying to make the database.

These are the core tables that the database will have:

Customer: which will have email, username, password....

Customers_Session: Stores information about customer session in hash

Group: basically tells what permissions a customer will have

Category: the category type of a product

Product: information about a product such as name, and description...

Product_Price: Price info on products. This will store the different prices put for each product at various times.

Product_Variation: information about product images, and various colors or styles of a product.

Customer_Orders: What products a customer has ordered.

Customer_Reviews: Reviews made by customers on a product.

Reviewed Products: This table is created based on many to many relationship between the Product table and the Review Table.

Ordered products: This table is created based on the many to many relationship between the Product and the Orders Table.

Based on the above, I have come up with the sql code below:

```
--
-- Table structure for table `users`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `username` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `first_name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `last_name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `address` varchar(320) NOT NULL,
  `zip` mediumint(5) NOT NULL,
  `salt` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  `joined` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `group` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `dob` date NOT NULL,
  `pic_url` varchar(225) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;

--


--
-- Table structure for table `groups`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `groups` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `permissions` text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;


--
-- This is for category table
--
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `category`(
  `category_id` tinyint(3) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `category_type` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `category_description` varchar(160) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`category_id`)
)ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
--


--
-- This is for product table
--
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `products`(
  `product_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `product_name` varchar(100) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
  `product_description` varchar(160) NOT NULL,
  `quantity` int(5) NOT NULL,
  `product_code` varchar(4) NOT NULL,
  `keywords` varchar(70) NOT NULL,
  `category_id` tinyint(3),
  PRIMARY KEY (`product_id`),
  INDEX (`category_id`),
  CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY (`category_id`) REFERENCES category(`category_id`) ON DELETE SET NULL
)ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
--


--


--
-- Table structure for table `bookings`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `bookings` (
  `bookings_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `party_type` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `location` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `day` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `time` smallint(6) NOT NULL,
  `people_count` smallint(6) NOT NULL,
  `booking_name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `booking_email` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`bookings_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COMMENT='This is for the bookings' AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;

--
-- Dumping data for table `groups`
--

INSERT INTO `groups` (`id`, `name`, `permissions`) VALUES
(1, 'Administrator', '{"admin":1}'),
(2, 'Users', '{"users":2}');

-- 
-- Table Structure for Reviews
--
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `customer_reviews`(
  `reviews_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` int(11),
  `rating` int(5) NOT NULL,
  `comment` varchar(160) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY(`reviews_id`),
  INDEX (`user_id`),
  CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY(`user_id`) REFERENCES users(`user_id`) ON DELETE SET NULL
)ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;

--

--
-- Table structure for reviewed products This is a many relationshi btw reviews table and product
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `reviewed_products`(
  `product_id` int(11),
  `reviews_id`int(11),
  PRIMARY KEY(`product_id`,`reviews_id`),
  CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY(`product_id`) REFERENCES products(`product_id`) ON DELETE SET NULL,
  CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY(`reviews_id`) REFERENCES customer_reviews(`reviews_id`) ON DELETE SET NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COMMENT='This is for many to many cardinality btw reviews and products' AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;

--


--
-- Table structure for table `orders`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `customer_orders` (
  `order_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `order_time` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `amount` int(5),
  `confirmation_number` int(,
  `user_id` int(11),
  `product_id` int(11),
  PRIMARY KEY (`order_id`),
  INDEX (`user_id`),
  CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES users(`user_id`) ON DELETE RESTRICT
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;

/* We need a new table since the customer_order and product is in a many to many relationship */
--


--
-- Table structure for table `curtomer_order_product`
--
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `ordered_product`(
  `product_id` int(11),
  `order_id` int(11),
  `quantity` smallint(5),
  PRIMARY KEY(`product_id`,`order_id`),
  INDEX (`product_id`,`order_id`),
  CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY (`order_id`) REFERENCES customer_orders(`order_id`) ON DELETE RESTRICT,
  CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY (`product_id`) REFERENCES products(`product_id`) ON DELETE RESTRICT
)ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
--
-- This is for price table
--
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `product_price`(
  `price_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `price` decimal(6,2) NOT NULL,
  `product_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`price_id`),
  INDEX (`product_id`),
  CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY (`product_id`) REFERENCES products(`product_id`) 
)ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
--


--
-- Table structure for table `product_variations`
--
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `product_variations`(
  `variations_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `color_name` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `color_value` char(6) NOT NULL,
  `product_id` int(11),
  `picture1` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `picture2` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `picture3` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`variations_id`),
  INDEX (`product_id`),
  CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY (`product_id`) REFERENCES products(`product_id`) ON DELETE RESTRICT
)ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;


--


--
-- Table structure for table `users_session`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users_session` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `hash` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  INDEX (`user_id`),
  CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY(`user_id`) REFERENCES users(`user_id`) ON DELETE RESTRICT
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

The problem is that when I try to run the above code in PHPmyadmin, I get an error stating "Cannot add foreign key constraint". This starts to happen when creating the customer_Reviews table and any other subsequent tables that require foreign keys.

My questions are:
1. Would you recommend designing the database this way.
2. Why am I getting the "Cannot add foreign key constraint" error?

Thanks.

Comment: At least one of your tables reference `user.user_id`, but your `users` table only has an `id` column.

Comment: ProTip: Even though phone numbers and ZIP codes are (sometimes!) entirely numeric, don't store them as `int` types. Pain and suffering are likely. The rule of thumb is, unless performing math on it is valid (can you multiply two phone numbers? add two ZIP codes?), it should be stored as a string/char/varchar.

Answer (score 1):

For a full quality review of your database design, you might try the [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com) sister site. At a glance, I don't see any glaring issues with your database design or your SQL.

The foreign key constraint is failing because you have misnamed the column in question.

```
 CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY(`user_id`) REFERENCES users(`user_id`)
```

should be:

```
 CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY(`user_id`) REFERENCES users(`id`)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Two-Bit Alchemist. Major over site on my end. I modified that and it worked until when I tried to add the "reviewed_products" table. It gave me the same Cannot add foreign key constraint. From your vire am I doing anything wrong on that end?